# How to update an IndexedDB item with autoincrement key?

Tags: javascript, updates, auto-increment, indexeddb

I created an object store with autoIncrement: `db.createObjectStore("items", {autoIncrement:true});`

Now I want to be able to update an item given its key and a new value, so I wrote this function:

```
let updateItem = (key, newData) => {
    let objectStore = db.transaction(["items"], "readwrite").objectStore("items");
    let request = objectStore.get(key);
    request.onsuccess = (e) => {
        let data = e.target.result;
        Object.assign(data, newData);
        let requestUpdate = objectStore.put(data);      
    };
}
```

However, instead of updating the value, it creates a new item with the new data. I think it makes sense since `e.target.result` does not contain any information about its key. So how do I update an element in such an object store?

Comment: @Josh yup.. It is a duplicate.. Sorry, I tried my best to search before asking.. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a key as a second parameter, like `objectStore.put(data, key)`.

> **key**
>
> The primary key of the record you want to update (e.g. from [IDBCursor.primaryKey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBCursor/primaryKey)). This is only needed for object stores that have an `autoIncrement` primary key, therefore the key is not in a field on the record object. In such cases, calling `put(item)` will always insert a new record, because it doesn't know what existing record you might want to modify.
>
> -- [IDBObjectStore.put() - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBObjectStore/put)

Comment: I found another solution but yours also solves the problem so I'm accepting it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution using `cursor.update()`:

```
let updateItem = (key, newData) => {
    let objectStore = db.transaction("items","readwrite").objectStore("items");
    objectStore.openCursor().onsuccess = (e) => {
        let cursor = e.target.result;
        if (cursor && cursor.key == key) {
            cursor.update(Object.assign(cursor.value, newData));
            cursor.continue();
        }
    };
}
```